# EJB Injection in ReSTEasy JBoss AS 7

Tags: resteasy, jboss7.x

Does anyone know if JBoss AS 7 has support for EJB injection in ReSTEasy applications per J2EE spec? I know this did not work in AS6 and was a known spec violation.

Thanks for any help/insights.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the EJB injection is supported. I will explain a trick to put everything together to work:

1. You have to create a file beans.xml on /Web-Inf/
2. You have to change your Application Class. Change singletons by class.

Example:

```
singletos.add(new HelloResource())
replace this line by empty or clazzes.add(HelloResource.class)
```

After that  you can use ejb injection on JBoss7 and RestEasy using ejb annotation @EJB.